# How to deploy Java Spring MVC project on OpenShift

Tags: java, spring-mvc, openshift

I am setting up Java Spring MVC project on OpenShift. The project is a Dynamic Web project,not maven. OpenShift is able to push the code from Github completely but its getting error during deployment.Also do we have to convert to War file to deploy?

I tried using different servers like wildfly and jdkopen thats available on OpenShift but they all give different errors.For JDKopen it gives No Jars found. And for wildfly all the built and deployment is complete but when i use my route /home, it shows 404.

The Error Code:

```
Starting the Java application using /opt/run-java/run-java.sh ...
 ERROR: Neither $JAVA_MAIN_CLASS nor $JAVA_APP_JAR is set and 0 JARs found 
 in /deployments (1 expected)
 exec java - javaagent:
  /opt/jolokia/jolokia.jar=config=/opt/jolokia/etc/jolokia.properties 
 -Xms64m -Xmx256m -XX:+UseParallelOldGC -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions - 
 XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=10 - 
 XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=20 -XX:GCTimeRatio=4 -XX:AdaptiveSizePolicyWeight=90 - 
 XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=100m -XX:ParallelGCThreads=1 - 
 Djava.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism=1 - 
 XX:CICompilerCount=2 -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError -cp . -jar
  Error: -jar requires jar file specification
  Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
        (to execute a class)
  or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
       (to execute a jar file)
  where options include:
  -d32    use a 32-bit data model if available
  -d64    use a 64-bit data model if available
  -server     to select the "server" VM
              The default VM is server,
              because you are running on a server-class machine.


  -cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
  -classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
              A : separated list of directories, JAR archives,
              and ZIP archives to search for class files.
  -D<name>=<value>
              set a system property
  -verbose:[class|gc|jni]
              enable verbose output
  -version      print product version and exit
  -version:<value>
              Warning: this feature is deprecated and will be removed
              in a future release.
              require the specified version to run
 -showversion  print product version and continue
 -jre-restrict-search | -no-jre-restrict-search
              Warning: this feature is deprecated and will be removed
              in a future release.
              include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
-? -help      print this help message
-X            print help on non-standard options
-ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
-enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
              enable assertions with specified granularity
-da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
-disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
              disable assertions with specified granularity
-esa | -enablesystemassertions
              enable system assertions
-dsa | -disablesystemassertions
              disable system assertions
-agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]
              load native agent library <libname>, e.g. -agentlib:hprof
              see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
-agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
              load native agent library by full pathname
-javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
              load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument
-splash:<imagepath>
              show splash screen with specified image
```

See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html  for more details.

The java web app to deploy successfully and my routes to work correctly